# ios - how to create todo list in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

I want to create an application that should write/view my `to-do` list and appointments with the contact.

Does anyone have any idea which library to use and how to implement it in ipad

Thanks for your Help,

Comment: Your question is to broad and sounds more like requirements then a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking at [EventKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for iOS. There's calendar and alarms and reminders. Read up.